# Image learning network other than gan series

Tags: tensorflow

What is the famous network that I can use in the network that inputs and outputs images of the same size of deep learning that can be used with tesorflow other than gan series?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of network architectures which can perform *auto-encoding* / *image-to-image translation*, e.g. ResNet [1](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet), UNet [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet), Variational Auto-Encoders (VAEs) [3](https://danijar.com/building-variational-auto-encoders-in-tensorflow/), etc.

Note that any of those architectures can be used for GANs generators. GAN methods can be seen as a slightly more complexed way to train these generative networks, using an adversarial loss along the generative one.

Some Resources:

1. [Github - tensorflow/models/resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet)
2. [Github - jakeret/tf_unet](https://github.com/jakeret/tf_unet)
3. [Article - Building Variational Auto-Encoders in TensorFlow by Danijar Hafner](https://danijar.com/building-variational-auto-encoders-in-tensorflow/)